# How to use one access token generated for multiple users request in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I am working on jmeter for the First time. I am  extracting the accesstoken and passing it on to other requests. but i am facing the issue that once I run it for 50 users the access token request is also running and becase of which other request is failing as new access token is generated and the request is failing to use that. I want to generate one access token for all the 50 request. I have tried keeping the request parted in two different thread groups.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avHfW.png)

Answer (score 0):

@oshin, I am also new here but I will try what I did that might help yours too. I used JSR223 PreProcessor to get that access token and passed that in my other thread with another JSR223 preprocessor which reads that accesstoken. And passed that token in my header manager. See if this helps you.

Get token
[image: Get token]

Read access token in the following thread
[image: Read access token]

Assign token to Header manager

[image: Assign token]

Answer (score 0):

1. [Don't use Beanshell](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/is-beanshell-dead), since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting
2. Don't use scripting when something can be achieved using built-in JMeter Test Elements (or [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/))

I would recommend:

1. Moving your "login" sampler under [setUp Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#setUp_Thread_Group) so it would be executed before the main thread group and only by 1 user
2. Storing the token into a JMeter Property via [__setProperty() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty)

   JMeter Properties are global and can be accessed by all threads in all thread groups so you will be able to use one token
3. Read the token using [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) where required.